# Given a realpath show it into an ImageView. (Using Glide Library)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm trying to do this with Glide library but it doesn't work, and I don't know what to do.

When I use this Intent, Glide works fine and load the selected image.

```
Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(gallery,PICK_PHOTO);
```

I load the image here.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==PICK_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

         Glide.with(this).load(data.getData()).into(imageView);
}
```

The code above works fine. But when I give the realpath nothing happens.

This is my image path.

```
imagePath="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG-20161029-WA0025.jpg"
```

I'm using this very simple code but it doesn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo);
    File imgFile = new  File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG-20161029-WA0025.jpg");
    Glide.with(this).load(imgFile).into(imageView);

}
```

I've tried with Bitmaps using this.

```
File imgFile = new  File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG-20161029-WA0025.jpg");
if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    //Glide.with(this).load(imgFile).into(imageView);
}
```

But it doesn't work either.

PD: my final project is putting some images previously storage in my SDcard and put them into a RecyclerView. But I want to figure out how to show the image given the real path first.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.melquiadesrodriguez.showimage">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I do this, but it seems impossible that it works.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo);
    File imgFile = new  File(getFilename());
    Glide.with(this).load(imgFile).into(imageView);

}

private String getFilename() {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(filepath + "/Pictures/IMG-20161029-WA0025.jpg" );
        if (!file.exists()) {
            return null;
        }
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the real path from the uri give from activityresult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==PICK_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

         String selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
         File imageUri = new File(selectedImagePath);

         Glide.with(this).load(imageUri).into(imageView);
    }
 }


private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String path;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        path = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        path =  cursor.getString(index);
    }
    assert cursor != null;
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
```

### EDIT

it seem like you want to access external sdcard

make sure you have permission to read or write in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

try this..

```
private String getFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(filepath + "/Pictures/IMG-20161029-WA0025.jpg" );
    if (!file.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

### Edit

Oh before that, i realize that, there are certain device which have different external file storage path..so basically getExternalStorageDirectory() will return `/storage/sdcard0`, so maybe you need to check the existance of external storage path

```
String filename; 

if(new File("/storage/extSdCard/").exists()) { 
  filename="/storage/extSdCard/";
} 
else if(new File("/storage/emulated/0/").exists(){
  filename = "/storage/emulated/0/";
}
else if(new File("/storage/sdcard1/").exists()){ 
  filename="/storage/sdcard1/";
} 
else if(new File("/storage/usbcard1/").exists()) { 
  filename="/storage/usbcard1/";
} 
else if(new File("/storage/sdcard0/").exists()) { 
  filename="/storage/sdcard0/";
}
else if(new File("/mnt/sdcard/").exists()){
  filename = "/mnt/sdcard/";
}

File imgFile = new  File(filename+"Pictures/IMG-20161029-WA0025.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){
  //set image
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ZeroOne for your answer, I used that code and works fine. What i'm trying to do is load the imageView given the real path. Something like this. File imgFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG-20161029-WA0025.jpg")‌​; Glide.with(this).load(imgFile).into(imageView);

Comment: i think you can't directly from root source... see edit

Comment: could you check the edit part?. Am I available to load images directly from my SD given the real path?.

Comment: I feel so stupid. that was the problem. I added the permissions to the manifest, but I didn't allow the application to get access to external storage in settings. I want to say thank you, your codes and advice helped me alot..